# rpi-update SSL certificate problem

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, rpi-update

Rpi-update fails due to some certificates errors:

```
rpi-update 
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** No hash received from github: https://api.github.com/repos/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/git/refs/heads/master
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

When I try to launch with -k option I get following error:

```
rpi-update  -k
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
Invalid git hash specified
```

My raspian is fully updated (aptitude update ; aptitude upgrade)

Comment: The message is printed by curl, not rpi-update.  The -k option is a curl option.   It has no meaning to rpi-update

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to run `rpi-update`?

Comment: > "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911 Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

Comment: What's the output of `date` when you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check system time. SSL(encrypted connections) will not work unless the correct time is set.

Use below command to set system time
sudo date -s "29 May 2019 11:58:00"